# Is it possible to define the initial position of a ScrollView in the xml?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I found some posts here on the stackoverflow that showed how to set the starting position of a ScrollView. Only none of them is via xml, I was wondering if that is possible.

Looking at the attributes of a ScrollView in android studio I found scrollX and scrollY, can they define the initial position of ScrollView?

[image]

And if scrollX and scrollY don't solve, is there any other attribute that can define the initial position of a ScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the [`android:scrollX`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:scrollX) and [`android:scrollY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:scrollY) attributes which are defined in the documentation as:

> The initial [horiztonal/vertical] scroll offset, in pixels.